# Eigenvalue Bound of Rayleigh Quotient for Normal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M=M^T\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ then the [Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) is $\frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx} \in [\lambda_{\min}, \lambda_{\max}]$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is a similar bound known if $M$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)? If so, how would one derive such a bound?

Comment: If $M$ is normal, then its [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) is the convex hull of its eigenvalues, but the fact that you are only considering real vectors $x$ changes things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any real vector $x$, we have $x^TMx = x^TAx$, where $A = \frac 12 (M + M^T)$ is the "symmetric part" (AKA "real part") of $M$.  The spectral theorem allows us to deduce that the eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely the real parts of the eigenvalues of $M$.

Thus, the range of values normal matrix $M$ is simply the interval between the smallest and largest of the real parts of its eigenvalues.